# how to share a non global variables between classes in python

Tags: python

I need to share a variable between 2 classes that are called in the main file. in the following replicable code, variable sharedVar is defined in main file and passed to both class child1 and child 2. I am expecting the variable to be equal to 2 in child2 since it has been changed from 1 to 2 in child1. but it still prints it as 1.

file mainClass:

```
from class1 import Class1
from class2 import Class2

class mainClass():
    sharedVar = 1
    my_child1 = Class1(sharedVar)  # expecting to print 1
    my_child2 = Class2(sharedVar)  # expecting to print 2
```

file class1

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self,sharedVar):
        sharedVar += 1
        print("Class1",sharedVar) # output is 2
```

file class2

```
class Class2():
    def __init__(self,sharedVar):
        print("Class2",sharedVar) # output is 1 but expected to be 2
```

Note: These classes are in 3 separate files, so defining a global variable outside the classes will not work!

If you have an answer, please be specific and provide the code. writing an explanation without codes is not going to help me nor the future readers of this question.

Comment: you need to apply inheritance

Comment: If you pass the argument by reference you will get the result you're looking for.

Comment: This is a key issue in understanding Python.  When you call `Class1(sharedVar),`, you are not passing "sharedVar".  You are passing that object that sharedVar is bound to.  In this case, the integer 1.  `sharedVar` in Class1 is totally unrelated to `sharedVar` in `mainClass`.  When you say `sharedVar += 1`, that is creating a new object (integer 2), and binding that to the local name `sharedVar`.  Nothing has changed in `mainClass`.  If you want to have  `sharedVar` be a `self` member, you could pass a `mainClass` object to the subclasses and change it.

Comment: @NicholasHunter If you think Python has "pass by reference", then you don't know Python very well.

Comment: @TimRoberts ofc you are correct. brain fart on my part. i was thinking in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

file mainClass:

```
from class1 import Class1
from class2 import Class2

class mainClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sharedVar = 1
        self.my_child1 = Class1(self)  # expecting to print 1
        self.my_child2 = Class2(self)  # expecting to print 2
```

file class1

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self,sharedObj):
        sharedObj.sharedVar += 1
        print("Class1",sharedObj.sharedVar)
```

file class2

```
class Class2():
    def __init__(self,sharedObj):
        print("Class2",sharedObj.sharedVar)
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Could you tell me if sharing the class object is the best practice? or if there are other ways to do that?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  Forcing the other two classes to have internal knowledge of a third class is not good isolation.  If you want to have a "State" object that holds state information that gets manipulated by others, that's reasonable.  Do Class1 and Class2 refine the behavior of mainClass?  Should they be subclasses?

Comment: Class1 is responsible for managing captured frames from a webcam and Class2 is pyqt gui, and Class3 reads sensors and send the data to Class2 to show on gui.  When Class1 detects motion, it saves the frame with an id and also Class2 records the data in a database and QtableView with that same id and it uses the sensor data to be recoreded with that same id. I cannot record data to database from within Class1 upon detected motion because it also needs sensor data from Class3. I must pass sensor data from Class3 to Class1 or I pass id from Class1 to Class2 (gui) which has access to sensor data.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you need a "controller" that owns all three objects and passes data between them.

Comment: could you give me an example? how should i write a controller?

Answer (score 1):

if you came from a c++ or java background, of course, this is what you expect to happen(If they are passed by reference), however, it's not like that in python.
variables here are a bit different, it's called identifier; when I say that x=5 this means python will create an object in memory of type int(let's call b1) and with value 5, and will let x point to that variable, so when I make x +=1 this mean that python will create a new object in memory (call it b2)of type int with value 6 and will let x now point to b2. so now b1 if left unpointed.

Another example:
if we say x=5, y=x--> then we have an object in memory of type int with value 5, and x and y point to it; so when I say x=9 I let x point to another object which is equal to 9, but still y points to 5

so when you send it to class1 it let x point just to a different object and in class2 it send the original object which is equal to 1.
I understood very deeply from Data structure and algorithms in python book I encourage you to read that section.

Comment: this answer could benefit from a code sample regarding your last paragraph. Also, it would be more user-friendly if you linked or provided a specific page of that book.